# If I randomly generate a string of length N from an alphabet {A, B, C}, what's the likelihood that exactly k characters will be the same?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

- I have an alphabet: {A, B, C}.
- I'm randomly generating strings of length N from that alphabet.

  Examples: Examples: N=5, AACBC, AAAAA, BBCAA
- What is the likelihood that *exactly* k characters of that string are the same? (k <= N)
  (k corresponds to the maximum number of similar characters...
  Example: With string AABCAAA: N=7, k=5 because there are 5 A's.
  String AABBCC: N=6, k=2 because there are equally-sized groups of A's, B's, and C's.)

Initially, my solution looked like this:
P(k characters are the same) = $(\frac{1}{3})^k * (\frac{2}{3})^{n-k}$
Until I realized that this solution wasn't robust enough-- it doesn't matter WHICH characters are the same, only that k characters are the same.

Thanks so much in advance for your help.

Comment: Not only that, you will have to consider permutations of each string. Hint: Since there are *three* categories instead of two, you can't use the *binomial* coefficient.

Comment: Did you mean $N=6$ for AABBCC?

Comment: @ByronSchmuland yes I meant N = 6! Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Do you mean "at least $k$ characters of the string will be the same"?

Comment: @DanielV I mean exactly k characters.

Comment: The probability is $\displaystyle\frac{1}{3^N} \sum_{(a,b,c)\in E} \frac{N!}{a!b!c!}$ where $E$ is the set of $(a,b,c) \in \{0,\dots,N\}^3$ such that $a+b+c = N$ and $\max(a,b,c)=k$.

Comment: @Siméon what's a precise way of calculating this? Could you post an example? Say, if N = 3 and two characters are the same (k = 2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let k, l, m be the # of occurrences for different letters in decreasing order.

Using the multinomial distribution formula, to illustrate,

for string AAABBC, Pr = **$\frac{6!}{3!2!1!}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^6$**

and for string AABBCC, Pr = **$\frac{6!}{2!2!2!}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^6$**

In general, Pr = **$\frac{N!}{k!l!m!}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^N$**, k+l+m = N

**continued...**

I have taken that you want probabilities for particular values of k. For k = 3 and N = 6, for example, you will need to sum up probabilities for permutations of 3-3-0 (3#s) & 3-2-1 (6#s)

**edited by the questioner...**
The final solution comes down to this.
Imagine that we have three bins, each representing the number of times each character appears in a string. For AAABC, the bins would be {A:3, B:1, C:1}
For:

- N = the length of the string,
- k = the maximum bin value (there can be ties),
- l = the next bin value,
- m = the last bin value,
- d = the number of bin values that are *different* from k's bin value (max 2)

  - Examples:

    1. ABC: bins = {A: 1, B: 1, C: 1}. d = 0
    2. AAA: bins = {A: 3, B: 0, C: 0}. d = 1
    3. AAC: bins = {A: 2, B: 0, C: 1}. d = 2
- C = the number of letters in our alphabet (always 3),

Pr = **$\frac{N!}{k!l!m!}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^N \cdot\frac{C!}{(C - d)!}$**, k+l+m = N

Comment: I'm not sure if this works for a few cases I've been using to test on. For example, if I generate a three-letter string (N=3), the probability that two of them are the same (k = 2) is $\frac{6}{9}$. I know this because I counted it out by hand.
When I apply the multinomial distribution formula:
$\frac{3!}{2!*1!*0!} * (\frac{1}{3})^3 = 1/9$

Comment: Read my "continued" portion. Since 2-1-0 has 6 permutations, you will need to multiply by 6, and you will get the correct answer.

Comment: Do you mean that I multiply by the number of permutations of k? Like:
Pr = **$\frac{N!}{k!l!m!}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^N * k!$

Comment: Also, what about in the case of 2 cards that are both different?  
$\frac{2!}{1!*1!*0!} * (\frac{1}{3})^2 * 2! = 4/9$, which isn't the correct probability.

Comment: Not multiply by k!, there  can only be  3 patterns for N = 3: all identical (1 permutation), 2 identical (3 permutations) and all different (6 permutations). Thus for the 1-1-0 case, you need to multiply by 3,(which arises as 3!/2!) not 2!

Comment: Is this formula generalizable to k and better? From k to N? That is, finding the probability that a string will see the same letter k times AND MORE?

Comment: $\sum_k^n \frac{N!}{k!l!m!}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^N \cdot X$, k+l+m = N, where X = 6 if {k,l,m} are  distinct, 3 if any pair is identical , and 1 if all are identical.

Comment: Yes, but while the value of `k` changes, how do `l` and `m` change? How do you decrement `l` and `m` while you increment `k`?  
Does it matter how you decrement them?

Comment: k,l,m were taken to be in decreasing order so for N = 4, as an example,   count back from N to k  viz 400, 310, 220, 211, but I am not a programmer ! The order doesn't matter as long as all get covered.